# Turning word wrap on in Notepad++ with 4MB+ text files makes it intolerably slow, how to fix?

Tags: performance, notepad++, word-wrap

When I edit long text files in Notepad++ (4MB) and turn the word wrap on, it causes about a second delay between typing a letter and seeing it appear, rendering the editor in this mode practically unusable.

Other editors (PSPad, JEdit, Editpad Lite) don't have this problem.

**What can I do in Notepad++ to allow it to not pause after each key stroke while I am editing 4MB text files with word wrap mode turned on?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try your file in `Notepad2` and `SciTE` as well.  If they just as slow, you can assume that it is a weakness of the underlying `Scintilla` library.

Answer (score 1):

You can try disabling any plugins and see if it helps. Unfortunately though, I think the ultimate answer if "Nothing" or "Switch Editors".

Answer (score 1):

Try to disable "smoothing edges of screen fonts". If you use Windows XP you can disable it in this way:

1. Right-click your Desktop.
2. Click "Properties".
3. Click the "Appearance" tab.
4. Click the "Effects" button.
5. If the "Use the following method to smooth edges of screen fonts" checkbox is checked you need to unchek it.